# Is there a platform where atomic_is_lock_free on shared_ptr<> returns true?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I'm currently reading "Concurrency in Action" by A. Williams and during a discussion on lock-free stack implementations, he mentions that if a platform returns `true` for `atomic_is_lock_free()` on a `shared_ptr<>` instance, then a `shared_ptr<>` can be used to cleanly implement the stack. However, the following on my platform (fedora, gcc 6.3.1 with c++14 option) returns `0`. So my question is, is there a platform where this returns true?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>

int main(void) {
  auto f = std::make_shared<int>(10);
  std::cout << std::atomic_is_lock_free(&f) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you essentially just asking "does an implementation exist where X is true?"

Comment: @TylerH: yes a - practical implementation?

Comment: @Mat There are [free functions added by `shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic)

Comment: @NathanOliver: Ah, neat. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I don't believe that such a platform/implementation exists

Comment: Williams's own implementation of the concurrency TS has an [`atomic_shared_ptr`](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/experimental_atomic/atomic_shared_ptr.html) that is lock-free for CPUs supporting double-width CAS.